# how to serialize String/null as json in quarkus?

Tags: jackson, resteasy, quarkus

quarkus serialize String as plain string, null as empty body(with http code 204)

"foo" -> foo

null -> (empty body)

how to make it serialize String and null as json like:

"foo" -> "foo"

null -> null

Comment: What response content type do you set? I suspect you set nothing or text/plain. If so, try explicitly setting it to application/json. This should fix "foo" -> "foo" problem, but I'm afraid the null will still be 204.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ObjectMapper` class for serializing/deserialising process in Quarkus.

> ObjectMapper provides functionality for reading and writing JSON, either to and from basic POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects)

First, you must be sure the `io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson` package exists in your `build.gradle` file. If it doesn't exist you can install it with this command:

`./gradlew addExtension --extensions="io.quarkus:quarkus-jackson"`

After that, you must get an instance:
`ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();`

You will find your need in this instance of ObjectMapper.

Answer (score -2):

You could try somhthing like this:

```
package org.acme.config;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/greeting")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String greetirng() {
        return "{\"greeting\": \"Hello, JSON\", \"penalty\": null}";
    }
        
}
```

Check it:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/greeting
{"greeting": "Hello, JSON", "penalty": null}
```